# PHPStorm - Process finished with exit code 255

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

I'm trying to make unit tests in Symfony 3 framework. Here are my configurations;
[image: Run/Debug Configirations]

[image: PHPUnit Preferences]

and here is the error that I'm facing.

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php /private/var/folders/w9/cmwlplqx53x3slxkm4c1chx00000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php --bootstrap /Users/muhammetergenc/code/kampweb/phpunit.xml.dist --configuration /Users/muhammetergenc/code/kampweb/phpunit.xml.dist Tests\AppBundle\Controller\PersonTest /Users/muhammetergenc/code/kampweb/tests/AppBundle/Controller/PersonTest.php
Testing started at 3:04 PM ...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="app/autoload.php">

    <!-- <phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
             backupGlobals="false"
             colors="true"
             bootstrap="web/app_test.php">-->
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I do have the same configuration on my other desktop and it works just fine.

Comment: You have set it to use the XML file as the bootstrap file, it then tries to run the XML as PHP and fails.

Comment: @JimL wouldn't it be ignored it if wasn't a PHP class that extends the PHPUnit framework though?

Comment: I unchecked the default bootstrap file option and still getting the same error. @JimL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today I had the same error - 255.
in my case I hadn't declared CONSTANTS in the setUp method.

I think that you have something similar.
Try to find it by using xdebug - it helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, It was a php error setting issue.

I set display_startup_errors to "1". and phpunit reported error.

Specifically, in my bootstrap script, I wrote below.

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```

And phpunit report my `require_once` runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a memory issue.

In the `setUp()` method I initialize multiple class properties.

The fix for me was defining (override) the `tearDown()` method to unset the properties after each test.

```
protected function tearDown(): void
{
    // clean memory
    unset($this->foo);
    unset($this->bar);

    parent::tearDown();
}
```